# load symbol of flash in flex at runtime

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4, runtime

Hey people, I've this huge problem loading a symbol from a swf file in the application at runtime.  I want to load it and pass it as a argument to another class where it could be used further. The symbol name is passed on from the array collection from the "o" object. Can anybody please tell me what's the right way to go about it.. Thanks in advance..!!

Following is the code for reference..

```
public override function Show(o:ObjectProxy):void
    {
        var _this:Weather;
        var _super:ContentItem;
        var item:WeatherItem;
        var items:ArrayCollection;
        var widgetCount:Number;
        var headlineFontSize:int;
        var conditionsIconThemeLoader:Loader;

        this.m_weatherWidgetContainer = new HBox();

        super.Show(o);

        _this = this;
        _super = super;

        (undefined == o["HeadlineFontSize"]) ? headlineFontSize = 20 : headlineFontSize = o["HeadlineFontSize"];

        if (undefined != o["direction"])
            this.m_textDirection = o["direction"];

        if (o.LargeUrl.Forecast is ArrayCollection)
            items = ArrayCollection(o.LargeUrl.Forecast);
        else
            items = new ArrayCollection([o.LargeUrl.Forecast]);

        widgetCount = this.m_computeWidgetSpace(items.length);

        conditionsIconThemeLoader = new Loader();

        conditionsIconThemeLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(e:Event):void
        {
            for(var i:uint = 0; i < widgetCount; i++)
            {
                var symbolClass:Class = e.currentTarget.loader.contentLoaderInfo.applicationDomain.currentDomain.getDefinition(int(items[i].condition)) as Class;
                var symbolInstance:Sprite = new symbolClass();

                item = new WeatherItem();
                item.Show(items[i], headlineFontSize, symbolInstance, widgetCount);

                _this.m_weatherWidgetContainer.addChild(item);
            }
        });

        conditionsIconThemeLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, function(e:IOErrorEvent):void
        {
            Alert.show("Failure loading " + WidgetStylesheet.instance.Weather_Widget_Theme + ".swf");
        });

        // Attempt to load theme weather icon file
        conditionsIconThemeLoader.load(new URLRequest("assets/animation/" + WidgetStylesheet.instance.Weather_Widget_Theme + ".swf"));

        super.media.addChild(this.m_weatherWidgetContainer);
    }
```

Comment: Can you tell what part it's getting up to? And also what it isn't doing? To make it easier can you trace out the following `e.currentTarget.loader.contentLoaderInfo.applicationDomain.currentDomain.getDefinition(int(items[i].condition))` and post the results as a reply to this comment.

Comment: hey chris thanx for responding so quick. I got the solution, i was'nt setting the LoaderContext to the current ApplicationDomain, odrwz it doesnt knows in which hierarchy level of domain should it look for the symbol. I m using following to set the LoaderContext:
loaderContext = new LoaderContext(false, ApplicationDomain.currentDomain);
and pass it as loader's load function argument.

Comment: I was just about to post the answer about the app domain.  Please answer your own question when you can.  Also, as a side note, try to not create anonymous functions for event listeners.  Please create a separate function and within that function remove the listener from the object if you don't need it anymore.

Comment: @chris: Ya buddy, i got it fixed, n its running like a charm without adding any weight to my main swf file.

Comment: #j_a_x: ya i did tht ryt away, my boss asked me to do so..hey wats ur real name..:P

Comment: @ductTape It would be really good if you put the fix in as an answer, and then a bit later you'll be able to mark that as Accepted. That way it will be really easy to tell that it's fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres the answer

```
public override function Show(o:ObjectProxy):void
{
    var _this:Weather;
    var _super:ContentItem;
    var conditionsIconThemeLoader:Loader;
    var loaderContext:LoaderContext;

    this.m_weatherWidgetContainer = new HBox();
    this.m_weatherWidgetContainer.percentHeight = 100;
    this.m_weatherWidgetContainer.percentWidth = 100;
    super.Show(o);

    _this = this;

    (undefined == o["HeadlineFontSize"]) ? this.m_headlineFontSize = 20 : this.m_headlineFontSize = o["HeadlineFontSize"];

    if (undefined != o["direction"])
        this.m_textDirection = o["direction"];

    if (o.LargeUrl.Forecast is ArrayCollection)
        this.m_items = o.LargeUrl.Forecast;
    else
        this.m_items = new ArrayCollection([o.LargeUrl.Forecast]);

    conditionsIconThemeLoader = new Loader();
    loaderContext = new LoaderContext(false, ApplicationDomain.currentDomain);

    conditionsIconThemeLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, this.m_loaderSuccess);
    conditionsIconThemeLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, this.m_loaderFail);

    // Attempt to load theme weather icon file
    conditionsIconThemeLoader.load(new URLRequest("assets/animation/" + WidgetStylesheet.instance.Weather_Widget_Theme + ".swf"), loaderContext);

    this.m_weatherWidgetContainer.addEventListener(FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE, this.m_drawHorizontalLine);

    super.media.addChild(this.m_weatherWidgetContainer);
}
```